# Ruby: these two koans have stumped me

Tags: ruby

I would have expected the answer for both of the koans below to be

```
:default_value
```

but the correct answer is apparently `:false_value`.

In the first one, I understand the unless statement to mean,

```
result = :false_value but not if the control statement is false.
```

Since the control statement is 'false' i.e `unless false`, result should therefore be :default_value.  Same thing for the second koan.

Please explain

```
def test_unless_statement
    result = :default_value
    unless false
      result = :false_value
    end
    assert_equal __, result
  end

  def test_unless_statement_modifier
    result = :default_value
    result = :false_value unless false

    assert_equal __, result
  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In both cases, the correct answer is `:false_value`.  You can think of it this way:

`unless` means `if !(...)`

`unless false` means `if !(false)` which means `if true`

Or just note that the double negatives cancel each other out.

Comment: is that the same for all languages, like JavaScript?

Comment: If they have the "unless" keyword, then sure.

Comment: that's so counterintuitive. According to your answer, "Unless true" means, "If ! true".  but in regular English, " Unless true" would mean "Unless it is true". I know programming is not a spoken language, but ...

Comment: In a real program you will NOT see false or true appearing in conditionals.  What is "it" anyway?

Answer (score 0):

The boolean literals confuse the koan. A better example is

```
p customers unless customers.empty?
```

Meaning, 'print the array `customers` unless it's empty'. Equivalently,

```
p customers if customers.size > 0
```